# Rounding Functionality in C#

Tags: c#

we want to round function when value is 2.01 then 3,when 2.2 the 3 when 2.99 then 3 when 3.0 then 3 how to achieve it please suggest..

Answer (score 5):

[Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Math.Ceiling.aspx)

> Returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to the specified number.

Comment: Only thing to have in mind is that `Math.Ceiling` returns a `Double` and not `int`, so if the OP really wants an `int` he would need to cast it.